# Vanilla JS: Check if element classList contains values from an array and remove them

Tags: javascript, css

I have a `div` as such:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">
```

Occasionally, it may also have one more class from an array `["success", "error", "warning"]`

How do I check if the element has any of the classes from that array and remove them, without removing the `modal` class?

What I'm doing is:

```
var modalAlertClasses = ['warning', 'error','success'];
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');    
for (var i = 0; i < modal.classList.length; i++) {
        if (modalAlertClasses.indexOf(modal.classList[i]) > -1) {
            modal.classList.remove[modal.classList[i]];
            console.log(modal.classList[i]);
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: modal.classList.remove is a function, so use `modal.classList.remove(modal.classList[i]);`

Comment: @JaromandaX Woops didn't notice i used square brackets for it! If you write the same as an answer, I will accept it as the right one! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try this code on three or more classes assigned to div? like <div class="warning error success modal">, it wont delete the error and model,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses the following

```
modal.classList.remove[modal.classList[i]];
```

but `.classList.remove` is a function, so should be written

```
modal.classList.remove(modal.classList[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var modalAlertClasses = ['warning', 'error','success'];
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');    


modalAlertClasses.forEach(function(entry) {
    if( modal.classList.contains(entry)){
         modal.classList.remove(entry);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="modal warning error" id="modal">
  modal
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The neatest way:

```
modal.classList.remove(...modalAlertClasses);
```

If not supported - plain js:

```
modalAlertClasses.forEach(function(el) {
  modal.classList.remove(el);
});
```

Comment: Awesome! What if it were the other way round? remove everything but the elements in array?

Comment: @blue_zinc You could iterate over the classList and check if the array contains that entry and remove it otherwise ... but a faster way would be to just remove everything and add the elements in the array:
`modal.className = "";` `modal.classList.add(...newClassArray);`